# Python google cloud function deployment failure - Madmom pip package

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-functions, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy a Python3.7 Google Cloud Function using the "madmom" python pip package, however specifying `madmom==0.16.1` in requirements.txt causes a deployment failure. When I remove madmom from requirements.txt, but leave the other pip packages, the cloud function deploys fine.

madmom pypi: https://pypi.org/project/madmom/

madmom github: https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom

I a deploying the function from Google Cloud Function's online editor: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/add

I have deployed Python Google Cloud Functions before and this is the first time I've had issues. Any help would be very appreciated! I've been trying to find solutions online all day and haven't found anything.

Requirements.txt:

```
Cython==0.29.12
ffmpeg==1.4
flask==1.0.2
madmom==0.16.1
mido==1.2.9
numpy==1.16.4
scipy==1.3.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.2
```

Google Cloud Function Deployment Failure:

> Deployment failure:
>
> Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\nCommand \"python setup.py egg_info\" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-wheel-qjxrm41i/madmom/\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "66F138B2"}}

I sincerely appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `madmom` package: it has a build-time dependency on `cython` and `numpy`, but they aren't declared properly. Cloud Functions (like most runtimes) installs all your dependencies at the same time, but `madmom` needs `cython` and `numpy` installed *before* it can be installed, which isn't configurable via a simple `requirements.txt` file.

I've made [a PR to fix this](https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom/pull/452), it's been merged and will probably be in the next release.

In the meantime, you can install `madmom` from the source repository by using the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
git+https://github.com/CPJKU/madmom.git#egg=madmom
ffmpeg==1.4
flask==1.0.2
```

(note that you shouldn't specify all the sub-dependencies of your top-level dependencies here (like `Cython` and `urllib3`, unless you're actually importing them in your Cloud Function)